# Java: Use reflection or store instance objects in list?

Tags: java, android, performance, reflection

how are you? I'm trying to do some dynamic method calls to get sql strings on various objects in Java (Android), but i'm stuck with some questions about performance and stability.

**Context Example:** Repository class onCreate method get all entity objects (tables) and call a method (getCreateTable for example) to get a sql string to execute.

Sure i can explicit call class by class caling each method, but i have other calls like "dropTables", "truncateTables" and etc, and i do not want to be repeating the same structure all the time.

```
public void CreateTables() {
    execute(Entity1.getCreateTable());
    execute(Entity2.getCreateTable());
    execute(Entity3.getCreateTable());
    [..]
    execute(Entity50.getCreateTable());
}

public void DropTables() {
    execute(Entity1.getDropTable());
    execute(Entity2.getDropTable());
    execute(Entity3.getDropTable());
    [..]
    execute(Entity50.getDropTable());
}
```

Until now i know i can do that in 3 diferent ways.

**1) Using reflection (currently in use):** Basicaly, i store all the objects class in a list, and then use the reflection to call the desired static method.But i know that reflection not always should be the first choice.

```
private final List<Class> entityList = new ArrayList<Class>() {
    {
        add(Entity1.class);
        add(Entity2.class);
        add(Entity3.class);
    }
};

public void createTables() {
    /* get all query strings */
    List<String> queryList = getQueryList("createTable");

    try {
        for (String query : queryList) {
            execute(query);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        [...]
    }
}

private List<String> getQueryList(String methodName) {
    List<String> queryList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Class<?> objectClass : entityList) {
        try {
            Method[] ms = objectClass.getMethods();
            for (Method me : ms) {
                if (me.getName().equals(methodName)) {
                    String query = (String) me.invoke(null);

                    if (query != null && query.length() > 0) {
                        queryList.add((String) me.invoke(null));
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            [...]
        }
    }

    return queryList;
}
```

**2) Storing object instance in list:** I can have a list with the objects instanced and then cast then into abstract parent class (or interface) and call the methods to get the sql string. In this case, i don't know if is a good practice to keep an list of instanced objects in memory, maybe this could be worst than use reflection depending on list size.

```
private final List<BaseEntity> entityList = new ArrayList<BaseEntity>() {
    {
        add(new Entity1(context));
        add(new Entity2(context));
        add(new Entity3(context));
    }
};

public void createTables() {
    for (BaseEntity entity : entityList) {
        try {
            execute(entity.getCreateTable());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

**3) Storing all the strings into JSON object:** I don't tested that one yet, but i'm sure with should work. I can call an "init" method to iterate over all objects and create that JSON object/array with all the sql strings (drop, create, truncate and etc).

I really appreciate if you share with me what you think about these approaches (pros and cons) or another better solution.

Comment: Hint: reflection is always your last choice. You only use it if no other approach solves your problem.

Comment: You could use Room, SQLDelight, greenDAO, or [various other existing frameworks for database access](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/25?sort=created).

Comment: @GhostCat is what i thought, but is even worse than using a list with a lot of object instances?

Comment: The usual thing: performance will suffer, and any bug in your code will only show up at runtime.

Comment: You have a lot of classes with a static method with the same name? That needs a redesign, not a solution.

Comment: @GhostCat performance suffer is never a nice thing.

Comment: @Shadov Yes, there is a lot of class that implement the same interface (entity/model class) and use basically the same methods: save, delete, update and etc...

Comment: Not all of the methods are statics. But, most of them return very similar strings, perhaps implementing some sort of method that dynamically generate this string could work (sometimes the simplest solution is the best one too). The problem would be the exception of some classes that have special rules to implement.

Comment: @GhostCat I don't think, performance could be a problem as we're dealing with a database access, which is even much slower. I don't have any figures, so I may be wrong. And yes, reflection is tricky and ugly, but writing the code manually is much uglier. And in the end, reflection is what all the frameworks use (unless they optimize it away using bytecode generation, which is even uglier).

Comment: @ThiagoYou That sounds like a bad design. As a user, you don't want your entities to return some SQL - it just doesn't belong there. I'd strongly suggest to use an existing framework, or, if you're very brave and determined, write your own.... but keep your entities out. There should be methods like `getDao(Entity1.class)` and `daoHelper.save(entity1)`.

Comment: @maaartinus using a framework really would be the best way, i'll look for something. What do you think that is slower, reflection or keep a list of instances? (between 30 or 50 items)

Comment: @ThiagoYou I don't know.... maybe reflection is a bit slower, but I wouldn't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it was a clarly a bad design (it's an old project that i'm refactoring). So i decided to get away from reflection and spend some time to redesign the code itself.

I created an base super class to handle all similiar methods and let the entities/models implement only the required individual rules, so DB access is stored in only one class as a Singleton. It's far better to use interface polymorphism.

In this way, the db class handle the dinamic SQL generation to avoid repeating the same code everywhere and re-use/recycle the list of instances to improve performance.

**Obs. 1:** Reflection throw down performance and usually let debbuging harder. Sure it can save some time as it is fast to implement, but will disable most of the IDE features, which makes it worthless in most cases.

**Obs. 2:** Keeping a list of DB instances active should never be done either. It's never a good idea to have many instances access database simultaneously, it can cause DB to lock and reproduce unexpectad issues.

**Obs. 3:** That JSON thing... forget about it. I'm sorry to suggest something so ugly.